# Sections in header... How?

Tags: article

I'm trying to write an article in LaTeX (in Texmaker), and would like to have the sections name in the right side of the header.
I can find how to do that with chapters in books, but is there a way to do it for articles??
Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! A minimal (non-)working example would help to help!

Comment: just add `\pagestyle{headings}` befor or after `\begin{document}`

Comment: @touhami Do you want to make that an answer? Or is the question too trivial?

Comment: @Johannes_B as you know, your wish is my command. So what can i do here?

Comment: @touhami You are in charge, it is your decision ;-)

Comment: @Johannes_B done ;-)

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved by adding `\pagestyle{headings}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}


\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```